# How do I convert dates in SqlLite from m/d/y to Y-m-d so that I can use strftime

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a set of data that I am importing into SqlLite, but don't really have the opportunity to manipulate it before insertion. I am trying to calculate "age" of the date, but this is proving very difficult in its current format.

I am looking for a select that I can use to update the data and then begin writing queries the way I want.

```
Data Samples
9/20/1983
2/18/1986
8/1/1994
5/29/1999

Desired
1983-09-20
1986-02-18
1994-08-01
1999-05-29
```

Once I have data in that format, I will calculate the date using the following

`(strftime('%Y', 'now') - strftime('%Y', Born)) - (strftime('%m-%d', 'now') < strftime('%m-%d', BOrn))`

I guess if there's a way to cast the date into the right format *and* calculate the age in one query, that would save a step, but I haven't been able to find a way so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following `update` statement to change the date format to YYYY-MM-DD:

```
update t
set    Born = 
       substr(Born, -4) || '-' ||
       substr('0' || substr(Born, 1, instr(Born, '/')-1), -2) || '-' ||
       substr('0' || substr(Born, instr(Born, '/')+1, 
                                  length(Born)-5-instr(Born, '/')), -2)
where  substr(Born, -5, 1) = '/'
and    Born LIKE '%/%/%'
```

The `where` clause is there to only update dates that have a **d/m/yyyy** format, where **d** and **m** could be two digits as well.

Comment: You have assumed the date is stored as a string.   I would expect it to have been stored as a `date`.

Comment: Sqlite has no date storage class.